# passwordless ssh not working

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, openssh

I've tried to setup a password-less ssh b/w  `A` to `B` and `B` to `A` as well.
Generated the public and private key using `ssh-keygen -trsa` on both the machines.
Used the `ssh-copy-id` utility to copy the public-keys from `A` to `B` as well as `B` to `A`.

The passwordless ssh works from `A` to `B` but `not` from `B` to `A`.
I've checked the permissions of the ~/ssh/ folder and seems to be normal.

`A's .ssh` folder permissions:

```
-rw-------  1 root root 13530 2011-07-26 23:00 known_hosts
-rw-------  1 root root   403 2011-07-27 00:35 id_rsa.pub
-rw-------  1 root root  1675 2011-07-27 00:35 id_rsa
-rw-------  1 root root   799 2011-07-27 00:37 authorized_keys
drwxrwx--- 70 root root  4096 2011-07-27 00:37 ..
drwx------  2 root root  4096 2011-07-27 00:38 .
```

`B's .ssh` folder permissions:

```
-rw------- 1 root root  884 2011-07-07 13:15 known_hosts
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  396 2011-07-27 00:15 id_rsa.pub
-rw------- 1 root root 1675 2011-07-27 00:15 id_rsa
-rw------- 1 root root 2545 2011-07-27 00:36 authorized_keys
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 4096 2011-07-06 19:44 ..
drwx------ 2 root root 4096 2011-07-27 00:15 .
```

`A` is an ubuntu 10.04 (OpenSSH_5.3p1 Debian-3ubuntu4, OpenSSL 0.9.8k 25 Mar 2009) `B` is a debian machine (OpenSSH_5.1p1 Debian-5, OpenSSL 0.9.8g 19 Oct 2007)

From `A`:

```
#ssh B
```

works fine.

From `B`:

```
#ssh -vvv A 
...
...
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/identity ((nil))
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7f1581f23a50)
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug3: Wrote 64 bytes for a total of 1127
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,gssapi,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/identity
debug3: no such identity: /root/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: Wrote 368 bytes for a total of 1495
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
root@192.168.122.1's password:
```

Which essentially means it's not authenticating using the file `/root/id_rsa`. 
I ran the `ssh-add` command in both the machines as well.

I'm running out of ideas.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Darn it, I'm having the exact same problem. Even if it was a little off topic to this forum, I wish someone would have provided a solution.